# Embedded Jetty post request high processing time

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am using eclipse Jetty 9.2.2. I am surprised to see that 10-12% of my request are taking around 500+ mili-seconds each while others get processed within 2-3 mili-seconds each. portion of the code taking time

```java
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(request.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
String postData = "";
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    postData+=line;
}

br.close();
```

Comment: Capture your traffic, and confirm that the Jetty even *received* the entire request in under 500ms from a network point of view.

Comment: Thanks Joakim, I have checked sar log and system health but couldn't find anything unusual. If you can guide with some more details on how to check and what parameter to check it would be great.

Comment: sar log is browser point of view, you should capture the network traffic, on the server side, that will tell you the truth from the server point of view.